# Add a databox to a plotly subplot

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to build a [tearsheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/dev/docs/report.jpg) where there will be charts on the left and data on the right. This is being exported from within a python financial application.

The plots are no problem but I cannot find online how to add the text box on the right side of the sub-plot.

Is there a way to add data in a chart box such as in the example linked above?

Comment: [Figure Factory Tables in Pytho](https://plotly.com/python/figure-factory-table/)There is an explanation of 'table' in the official reference. Is this helpful to you?

Comment: @r-beginners That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.